# Objective C syntax to assign a value to a variable property in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

My current project is in Objective C and I want to make new implementations to it in Swift.

In my Objective C class, I need to assign a value to my swift variable property but I don't know the syntax to do it. I want to assign the value like this.

```
self.pollBarGraph = [[PollBarGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

//I want to replace this with obj-c syntax to make it work
        self.pollBarGraph.dataEntries =
        [
           BarEntry(score: 100, title: "A"),
           BarEntry(score: 35, title: "B"),
           BarEntry(score: 55, title: "C"),
           BarEntry(score: 3, title: "D"),
           BarEntry(score: 10, title: "E")
        ]
```

PollBarGraph is the Swift file that I added and inside of it:

```
class BarEntry: NSObject {
        let score: Int
        let title: String

        init(score: Int, title: String) {
            self.score = score
            self.title = title
        }
    }

    @objc open var dataEntries: [BarEntry] = []{
        didSet {
            //my code
        }
    }
```

How can I assign the value to my Swift variable using Objective C syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need `didSet`, because you already have the value when you assign it. You use `didSet` to do some extra side effects when the value has been set, e.g. some calculations, invalidating something etc. But that's not the case here.

So first you need to specify your classes in your swift code correctly, e.g.

```
class BarEntry: NSObject {
    let score: Int
    let title: String

    @objc init (score: Int, title: String) {
        self.score = score
        self.title = title
    }
}

class PollBarGraphView : UIView {
    @objc open var dataEntries = [BarEntry]()  // default: empty array
}
```

Don't forget to expose your `BarEntry.init` via `@objc`.
To use it in Objective C, the syntax is as follows:

```
PollBarGraphView *pb = [[PollBarGraphView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
pb.dataEntries = @[
                    [[BarEntry alloc] initWithScore:1 title:@"A"],
                    [[BarEntry alloc] initWithScore:2 title:@"B"],
                    [[BarEntry alloc] initWithScore:3 title:@"C"]
                  ];
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and teaching! I'm new in Swift and your answer really helps a lot in understanding swift and objc interoperability .